# Different AES 256 algorithms produce different results?

Tags: tls, aes, openssl

I've tried 3 AES 256-bit CBC encryption programs, and I seem to be getting different results for each one with the same 32-character password, which consists of all @ signs.

They are:

```
Polaris SSL AES-256 (C code)
OpenSSL "enc" command (command line)
Some random website that uses Javascript to implement AES (website)
```

Is there so much variation in AES implementations that a file that is encrypted with one AES program cannot be decrypted with another one's?

Comment: As a sidenote: You shouldn't feed a 32 character password to AES, but rather a 32 byte key. If you want password based encryption, you should first hash then password with PBKDF2 or a similar slow KDF to produce the key instead of using the password directly.

Answer (score 6):

AES in CBC mode starts with a random initialization vector for the first block of data.

This is a randomly chosen 256-bits of data, that comprises the first block.  Other modes, such as ECB mode do not have this feature of a random initialization vector and always encrypt the same block of plaintext into the same ciphertext.  This leaks out information.

See: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation